# IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 debugger not working with Griffon 1.1.0 project

Tags: intellij-idea, griffon

I'm trying to debug a Griffon 1.1.0 project with InelliJ IDEA 12.0 but breakpoints are not being hit. The command I'm executing is `test-app -integration`. It runs fine, but without any debugger interaction. If I use the default JUnit Runner, then breakpoints are hit as expected, but none of the Griffon framework features are available, what is a requirement for my integration tests.

The "Debugger" tab in IntellyJ IDEA shows `Connecting to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51778', transport: 'socket'`, but doesn't seem to connect to the running VM (which expects a debugger on port 5005).

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA, so I might be missing something here...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,

Guillermo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created issue on IntelliJ bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97130
This will be fixed in 12.0.1 or 12.0.2.

As workaround you can create separate Remote Run Configuration that connects to localhost:5005 and run this Remote Run Configuration immediately after running of Griffon Run Configuration.

Comment: Thanks for filling in that bug report, I'll look forward to seeing it solved. The workaround works... and it'll help improving my reflexes! :P

Comment: I've just updated to 12.0.1 and the issue is solved. Thanks again.